# Is it possible to change the signature of an application published on google play?

Tags: google-play

Not long ago I published an app on Google Play with a certain signature, but I forgot the password, so I can't regenerate my signed abb.

I would like to know if there is any way to change the signature in the store, or if there is any way to recover my password.

PS: Don't ask how I lost my password, It´s a long story.